# How can I change an image using javascript (jQuery & iviewer) by adding 1 to the img src incrementally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Checked various questions on SO, but found nothing that quite matches what I'm after...

I'm buildling an image viwer using a combination of jQuery and [iViewer](https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/wiki/). Here's the code that's used to call different images in iviewer:

```
$("#chimg").click(function()
{
   iv1.iviewer('loadImage', "img/01.jpg");
   return false;
});
```

As can be seen, I've named the images sequentially. Right now, all the images are called using individual links, one per image, but ideally I'd like to be able to add previous and next image buttons as well.

Since the images are sequentially named, I was wondering if there was a method of calling the next image in a sequence by adding the value of '1' to the current image? Obviously, I'm happy to change the naming conventions of the files if this is necessary.

(Disclaimer: I'm a fast learner, but I'm also new to javascript. Solutions that are talked through would really be preferred...)

Comment: @FelixKling - I'm an absolute beginner, as the song goes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
var i = 0;

$("#chimg").click(function()
{
    i++;
    iv1.iviewer('loadImage', "img/" + ("0" + i).slice(-2) + ".jpg");
    return false;
});
```

This...

```
("0" + i).slice(-2)
```

...adds 0 to the beginning of whatever value is stored in i and then takes the last 2 characters, so you've got your 0 padded number.

Comment: You might want to toss in some comments explaining the parseInt and shorthand if.

Comment: @Archer - cheers very much for this! I have to go away overnight but I'll be back at my desk tomorrow to see if I can figure this out.

Comment: I'm about to make a slight change to the code - found a very simple way of handling the padding, without the use of parseInt, so it will make the code easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks @Archer, that looks simple enough for me to understand, even with my basic Java. One question though: I gather that 'i++' would be the value before the increment is added - is that correct? (Just so I know I've got everything.)

Comment: Yes mate - `i++` is the same as `i = i + 1`

Comment: Works great so far. A couple more questions I'm afraid (bear with me @Archer, I reckon this'll be just about the last round).

First, I've noticed that the first click on the next image link doesn't do anything, but that the second click does. Changing:

    var i = 0;

to

    var i = 1;

negates this problem. Why might this be?

Second, what would be the method to make this work in reverse, i.e. to call the previous image in the series? I assumed ("0" - i) or even ("0" + -i) might do the trick, but clearly I'm wrong in that assumption.

Comment: @shngrdnr Without seeing the page itself, I can't answer why you need 2 clicks for it to work.  It _should_ work with 1, from what you've told us.  As for doing it the other way round, start i at the highest image number instead of 0 and use `i--` instead of `i++`.

Comment: Perfect. I set 'i' for the previous function to be 99, as I'm going to use the same code on different pages with varying series lengths. Seems to work fine in all browsers, so now I'm a happy bunny. Cheers @Archer!

Answer (score 0):

i have never used iViewer before but first option off the top of my head is can you get the 'src' attribute for the img?  if you have the source you can get the number via regular expression

```
var src = $('#chimg').attr('src');
var m = parseInt(src.match(/\d+/g));
n = m+1;
src = src.replace(m, n);
iv1.iviewer('loadImage', src);
```

then whatever else you have to do.

[see it work](http://jsfiddle.net/ajdepoti/JGhan/)

Comment: This doesn't really answer anything the OP asked.

Comment: how so?  it loads the next incremental image in the sequence?  Please explain why you voted me down Jack.  OP asked how he can load images just by incrementing the number in the image name.  my code above has done exactly that.

Comment: I missed the part where you actually changed the value. You can't assume `#chimg` is the image though.

Comment: yea i wasn't sure about that.  I tried finding documentation on iViewer since i haven't used it before and didn't see anything about ID on the image itself so you make a Good point.