# How can I get the current src of jquery-based iviewer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-plugins

I'm currently using the jquery-based [iviewer](https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/wiki) for an online image gallery. This is the code being used to call the initial iviewer source image (edited for brevity):

```
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){
var iv1 = $(".viewer").iviewer({
    src: "/folder/001.jpg", 
});
```

After asking [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113913/how-can-i-change-an-image-using-javascript-jquery-iviewer-by-adding-1-to-the) elsewhere on SO, I'm currently using this method to drive next/previous buttons by adding '1' to the current image src on click (all images are named incrementally using three digits - 001.jpg, 002.jpg and so on):

```
var i = 1;

$("#next").click(function()
{
    i++;
    iv1.iviewer('loadImage', "/folder/" + ("00" + i).slice(-3) + ".jpg");
    return false;
});
```

However, the problem is that elsewhere on the same page I'm using some jquery code to change the displayed image in the iviewer on the basis of the class attribute of the relevant links (which are numbered similarly to the images - chimg001, chimg002 and so on):

```
$("ul.imageThumbs > li > a").click(function()
{
    var k = $(this).attr("class");
    iv1.iviewer('loadImage', "/folder/" + ((k).slice(-3)) + ".jpg");
    return false;
});
```

(I'm new to both jquery and javascript so I'm happy to hear any suggested mods to the above.)

After using the above code to display new images, the next and previous buttons don't change relative to the newly-displayed image, but only according to the last image accessed via the next/previous buttons.

I'd like to be able to have the next and previous buttons working by first finding the current src of the iviewer and then add one to that, rather than the current method. Can this be done?

Comment: The functionality I was after has been answered by the plugin's author, Dmitry Petrov. The answer's on [the project's github page](https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/issues/20).

Answer (score 0):

From reading the documentation for the plugin at the link you provided, there are a few parts that may be useful.

> info(prop, dropRotation) - get some info about the image. Valid values for prop are: display_width, display_height - current physical dimensions of the image; orig_width, orig_height - dimensions of the original image; angle - current rotation angle; zoom - current zoom value in %; src - url of current image;
>
> All the methods should be called through jquery ui notation: $('#viewer').iviewer('method', 'arg1', 'arg2')

So, try something like this:

```
$('.iviewer').iviewer('info','src');
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony! I'll give that a go and get back to you (it was the syntax that was stumping me, noob that I art)

Comment: Thanks Anthony - I've given this a go without success:

`$("#next").click(function()
 {
  i++;
  var j =    $(".viewer").iviewer('info','src');  
  iv1.iviewer('loadImage', "/folder/" + ((j.slice(-3)) + i) + ".jpg");
  return false;
 });`

This was on the assumption that it would (1) get the current src by the method you suggested, as variable 'j', (2) slice the last three digits of that variable (thus giving the correct filename), (3) add 1 to that value (variable 'i') and append that to the appropriate folder structure with the file type jpg. 

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @shngrdnr Check that there aren't any Javascript errors in your browser, and also try to output the value of `j` once you've retrieved it to see what it's returning (if anything). Having never used the plugin, and the documentation I read being pretty limited, the syntax I guessed at may be incorrect.

Comment: Checked those Anthony. Firebug is showing no javascript errors. Altering the code to alert(j) gives [object Object]. So it seems the syntax *might* be wrong (I agree the documentation is rather limited).  Interesting to note that using the code I quoted following your feedback, no images displaying on using the next button, but the previous button (which retained the code from my original q) worked as if it had. So presumably the number appending through 'i' is working and when the prev function slices the numbers it can still find the correct image.

Comment: another quick note, as it might help matters. I've also tried the code `var j = $(".viewer").attr('src');` which gives the message 'undefined'. Cheers for the help so far by the way